# Set up monolog to use rollbar with symfony3?

Tags: monolog, symfony-3.2, rollbar

config.yml

```
handlers:
        rollbar:
            type: stream
            token: '%rollbar.token%'
            level: warning
            bubble: true
            config:
                environment: '%rollbar.environment%'
        main:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:  debug
```

There is no activity on rollbar

```
$this->get('logger')->warning('testing rollbar');
```

I have tested their own code (using rollbar/rollbar) which works OK (from below instructions)

https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar-php/#installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got Rollbar on my own Symfony app, but it looks like you have the `type` set to just send it to the standard log files.

```
rollbar:
    token: "%rollbar_serverside_token%"
    type:  "rollbar"   ## This enables the Rollbar handler
    config:
        environment: "%kernel.environment%"
        handler: blocking
    level: debug
```

Since I've grouped the Rollbar handler under a 'fingers_crossed' main/default handler, it only throws items to the outside service if an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks, how did you get around rollbar/rollbar not being symfony compatible? It's pretty old code and doesn't have namespaces